# How can I create a simple copy and save function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, copy, save

Ok, so I'm basically trying to create a custom function in Google Sheets ( hardcore noob alert ) that would basically copy the number from a cell and keep it rather than changing every time the number changes.

Ex: I have 2 sheets, we'll call them 1 and 2

I have some numbers in 1

I copy the numbers in 2 using the ='1'!cell  function

BUT now the only thing I'd need would be another copy of the numbers in sheet 2 ( like a copy of the copy ) but independent from the source like if I change the original numbers the copy would need to stay the same, more like a copy and save function.

I really hope some hero there can actually understand what I wrote here and help me as I'm not to good at explaining but no worries if not.

Oh, and if it helps, I'm using:

```
function copyValue(cell){

  return cell;
```

to copy the value but I don't know what to do to keep the number after copying it.

Answer (score 0):

you could just use **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>** to paste values independently of everything else

Comment: the issue is that i can't do it manually every time the original numbers change, so if there is something like an automatic  CTRL + SHIFT + V that would be what I'm looking for